# Tools::isSubmit no working on Prestashop 1.7.8.10

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop-1.7

I have a admin form like this:

```
{if isset($image_description)}
    <p>Descripción de la imagen: {$image_description}</p>
{/if}

<form action="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{$token}" />
    <label for="image_upload">Subir Imagen</label>
    <input type="file" name="image_upload" id="image_upload" required>
    <br>
    <textarea name="image_description" rows="5" placeholder="Descripción" required></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="upload_form" value="Guardar">
</form>
```

And in my customgallery.php module, have this function:

```
   public function getContent()
    {
        $output = '';
        var_dump('Hola estoy en el inicio del getContent');
   
        if(Tools::isSubmit('upload_form'))
        {
            error_log('Hola estoy en dentro  del submit del getContent');

            $imageUpload = $_FILES['image_upload'];
            $imageDescription = Tools::getValue('image_description'); 

            if (empty($imageDescription)) {
                $output .= $this->displayError($this->l('Por favor, ingresa una descripción para la imagen.'));
            } else {
                $fileExtension = strtolower(pathinfo($imageUpload['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                $allowedExtensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

                if (in_array($fileExtension, $allowedExtensions)) {
                    $targetDirectory = _CUSTOMGALLERY_IMG_DIR_;
                    $fileName = 'image_' . date('YmdHis') . '.' . $fileExtension;
                    $targetPath = $targetDirectory . $fileName;

                    if (move_uploaded_file($imageUpload['tmp_name'], $targetPath)) {
                        $imagePath = pSQL($targetPath);
                        $imageDescription = pSQL($imageDescription);

                        $sql = "INSERT INTO `"._DB_PREFIX_."customgallery_images` (`image_url`, `image_description`) 
                                VALUES ('$imagePath', '$imageDescription')";

                        try {
                            if (Db::getInstance()->execute($sql)) {
                                $output .= $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('Imagen cargada correctamente.'));
                            } else {
                                $output .= $this->displayError($this->l('Error al insertar la imagen en la base de datos.'));
                                error_log("Error al insertar la imagen en la base de datos: " . Db::getInstance()->getMsgError(), 3, _PS_ROOT_DIR_ . '/log/customgallery.log');
                            }
                        } catch (Exception $e) {
                            $output .= $this->displayError($this->l('Excepción al insertar la imagen en la base de datos: ') . $e->getMessage());
                        }
                    } else {
                        $output .= $this->displayError($this->l('Error al mover la imagen al directorio de destino.'));
                        error_log("Error al mover la imagen al directorio de destino.", 3, _PS_ROOT_DIR_ . '/log/customgallery.log');
                    }
                } else {
                    $output .= $this->displayError($this->l('Tipo de archivo no válido. Por favor, sube una imagen válida.'));
                }
            }
        }
        

        // Muestra el formulario
        $form = $this->displayForm();
        $output .= $form;

        return $output;
    }
```

This function validates fields of form, the form has an image and a description, if I quit the if(Tools::isSubmit('upload_form')), the admin forms works well, but shows all errors of validating, but puts image in bbdd and in folder. If I uncomment this if, the form doesnt put image in bbdd and doest put image in folder /img. What happened? What am I doing wrong?